# Set-AzureADUserPassword - does the password get written back to the local domain via AAD Connect?

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I've found this MS support page which details under what conditions a password reset initiated on the Azure site is written back to the local domain using Azure Active Directory Connect: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3187256/password-isn-t-synced-from-azure-ad-to-the-local-on-premises-directory

What it doesn't list is whether the AzureAD cmdlet "Set-AzureADUserPassword" will or won't write back to the local domain. I'm able to reset the password manually from the Azure Portal AAD Mgmt site and have therefore been able to confirm that the password writeback process is working but haven't had any success yet with Set-AzureADUserPassword and would like to know if anyone has had any success with this method or can confirm that it won't work?

The purpose of this is to use a PowerShell script to reset a local domain password without the account being set to "User must change password on next logon" which happens when it is done via the WebGUI method.

Many thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Any end users trying resetting their own password by using PowerShell version 1, version 2 the password write back option is not supported.

Any administrator-initiated end-user password reset from PowerShell version 1, version 2 is also not supported.

Kindly check the unsupported write back options from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-wr)

Comment: Aghhh - I'm so sorry - I missed the notification that someone had replied!  Really do appreciate you getting back so really sorry about that!  The link you've provided ends up as a 404 for me but I get the gist - it's not going to work so I've found a different way instead (for info; because the AADConnect server is linked via VPNs to the local domain and required LDAP access I'm able to use Set-ADAccountPassword and specificy the local domain controller. This way I've been able to set the password against the local DC without having to worry about Azure password sync. Thanks again, Martin

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_73WvoPgsVMUTDq5&Q_CHL=gl
>